# vim airline arrows misaligned

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

The arrows should look like this:
[image]

here's what they currently look like
[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: will try! hopefully it's just the font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like these misaligned triangles are characters. All characters (the triangles and text) are too high according to the background. I guess this could happen if you used a superscript font.

Change the font in your terminal emulator.